# Animate only when section is being viewed on screen

Tags: jquery, animation, responsive-design

I am trying to animate simple bars, and they do, but I want the bars to be animated ONLY when that section is on screen.

My website is only one html doc and all the sections are in that same document, so I want the user to be able to see the animation happening once they scroll to that section.

I am thinking a simple if statement would work but idk how to state the condition. 
I was thinking once the #skills div top margin == window top 0 but idk if it's possible.

Can you help me please? :)

this is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
        if(#skill section is on screen){
            jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
                width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
            },2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test below code and enjoy....

```js
function  checkInView(elem,partial)
{
    var container = $(".scrollable");
    var contHeight = container.height();
    var contTop = container.scrollTop();
    var contBottom = contTop + contHeight ;
 
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top - container.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    var isTotal = (elemTop >= 0 && elemBottom <=contHeight);
    var isPart = ((elemTop < 0 && elemBottom > 0 ) || (elemTop > 0 && elemTop <= container.height())) && partial ;

    return  isTotal  || isPart ;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".scrollable").scroll(function(){
    var result="",result2="";
   $.each( $(".scrollable p"),function(i,e){
       if (checkInView($(e),false)) {
           $( this ).addClass( "red" );
       } else {
           $( this ).removeClass( "red" );
       }
        result += " " +  checkInView($(e),false);
       result2 += " " +  checkInView($(e),true);
    });
    $("#tt").text(result);
    $("#kk").text(result2);
});
});
```

```css
.scrollable{
    margin:10px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
p
{
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
full:  <div id="tt"></div>
part: <div id="kk"></div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <p>item1<span></span></p>
    <p>item2<span></span></p>
    <p>item3<span></span></p>
    <p>item4<span></span></p>
    <p>item5<span></span></p>
    <p>item6<span></span></p>
    <p>item7<span></span></p>
    <p>item8<span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you!! I finally ended up using:

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
 $(".skillbar").each(function() {
  /*if skillbars are visible on viewport*/
  if ($(".skillbar").visible(true)) {
   $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({width:$(this).attr('data-percent')},3000); 
     } 
   });
});

but I'll try your method :D